# Not receiving iOS Push notification from Parse.com for different Time zone

Tags: ios, parse-platform, notifications, push

I have resisted some devices from Asia/Kolkata time zone and some devices from Europe/London.

When I push notification by following below steps -

1) Choose Your Recipients  - Everyone
2) A/B Testing  - Use A/B Testing - No
3) Choose a Delivery Time - Now
4) Expires - No
5) Write Your Message - Hi All, This is test notification
6) Message Type- Plain Text
7) Increment App Badge - Yes
8) Send Now

I received notification on Asia/Kolkata time zone device but not on other time zone.

Can you please help me to resolve this issue.